# Dataset not recognized in new form

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset

I have used my Dataset all over the project without any problem.

When I Add a new form , the Dataset is not recognized in it - JUST THE NEW FORM.

It says :
`The name 'mydataset' does not exist in the current context`

I have checked `using System.Data.SqlServerCe;` `using System.Data.SqlClient;` is in the `form.cs`.

I tried to declare new one in `form.cs` and it doesn't work.

form.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace O2
{
public partial class ProductSelect : Form
{
    public ProductSelect()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ProductSelect_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DatabaseDataSet ds = new DatabaseDataSet();

        foreach (DataRow row in mydataset.Products.Rows)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(row["Product_Name"]);
        }

    }
}
}
```

Any help ?

Edit :
form2 where `mydataset` works perfect (without declaring it) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace O2
{
public partial class SalesBill : Form
{

    public SalesBill()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void SalesBill_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     foreach (DataRow row in databaseDataSet.Clients.Rows)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(row["Client_Name"]);
        }

    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: I don't see where you have declared "mydataset".

Comment: I have not declared it before in other forms and it works perfect. I've commented the line where I declared a new one

Comment: You said you used it all over your project, is it a typed dataset? Please show code where it's working.

Comment: As @thewisegod is getting at, your other forms must be using typed datasets. These will be declared in the ...designer.cs file. ANY object you use MUST be instanciated somewhere. You cannot just make up a varible name and start using it.

Comment: @Crowcoder I've checked that. That's right. But why the new form doesn't generate this like the others ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you are using the designer for configuring the form and elements on it, from toolbox in Data section, drag an DataSet and drop it on form. You can select either [typed dataset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/314t4see(v=vs.110).aspx) or untyped dataset
- If you want to create and use dataset from code, consider declaring your dataset variable and create an instance of your typed or untyped dataset.

open form 2 at designer you probably will see a component with name databaseDataSet in component tray of it. It seems you are using a typed dataset.

And if you look at Data Source window (Shift+Alt+D) you will see a node of DatabaseDataset with some child node that are your tables.

You can drag clients table and drop it on form.

Comment: It worked. Thanks.
But why the new form doesn't generate this like the others ?

Comment: Probably you have dropped it from data source window on other forms.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET you declare a dataset like this:

```
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare DataSet as global

```
public static readonly DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet();
```

And access in other forms as

```
CLassName.MyDataSet; // ClassName is that in which you declare your dataset
```

But the recommended way is that, you need to add DataSet from toolbox or from new item dialog and add required tables into it.

[image]